# Unable to install Kubernetes on AWS using kops

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kubectl, kops

I have tried to install Kubernetes on Amazon Linux Machine. I followed a lot of documents and videos in those tutorials they are easily installing kubectl and kops but in my case, I followed the same steps but kubectl is not working for me.

error: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port? I opened all required ports still effecting with the error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) kubelet is not a service, it's just a binary executable file so there is no any service unit file for it on your system

2) How did you use kops to deploy cluster on aws? I always use the following steps which work for me:

Install `awscli`

```
sudo apt-get install python python-pip
sudo python-pip install awscli
```

Create aws credentials for your **admin user** (using IAM) and configure your awscli utility to use them

```
aws configure
```

Install `kops`

```
curl -LO https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/releases/download/$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kops/releases/latest | grep tag_name | cut -d '"' -f 4)/kops-linux-amd64
chmod +x kops-linux-amd64
sudo mv kops-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/kops
```

as well as `kubectl`

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
apt-get update
apt-get install -y kubectl
```

Create `s3 bucket` for Kubernetes's storage with some name

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket k8s --region eu-central-1 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-central-1
aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --region eu-central-1 --bucket k8s --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled
aws s3 ls
```

Create hosted zone (or subdomain) for Kubernetes cluster in Route53 or use existed one in `Route53`, for example `test.com`.

Create cluster via kops:

```
kops create cluster --name=k8s.test.com \
                    --state=s3://k8s \
                    --zones=eu-central-1a \
                    --node-count=2 \
                    --node-size=t2.small \
                    --master-count=1 \
                    --master-size=t2.micro \
                    --master-zones=eu-central-1a \
                    --dns-zone=test.com \
                    --authorization=RBAC \
                    --yes
```

wait for a while and check if it's running:

```
kops validate cluster --name=k8s.test.com --state=s3://k8s
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.after creating the  cluster if we want to run the pods have to use kubectl commands but kubectl is not working.on Ubuntu machine I can able to create the cluster and run the pods but same is not working on Amazon Linux Ami.

Answer (score 0):

> error: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

In most cases, this error message is displayed when the `kubectl` configuration of your cluster is not set up correctly.

### Basic information

By default ‘kubectl’ configuration file is located in `$HOME/.kube/config` and contains the following sections:

**Cluster information:**

- hostname/ip:port of your kubernetes master node with running kube-apiserver
- certificates required to connect to the kube-apiserver

  ```
  clusters:
  - cluster:
      certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
      server: https://10.156.0.3:6443
    name: kubernetes
  ```

**User information:**

- User name
- User certificate

  ```
  users:
  - name: kubernetes-admin
    user:
      client-certificate-data: REDACTED
      client-key-data: REDACTED
  ```

**Context information:**

- combinations of cluster and user references
- current context that is used if no context is specified in `kubectl` command line

  ```
  contexts:
  - context:
      cluster: kubernetes
      user: kubernetes-admin
    name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
  current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
  kind: Config
  preferences: {}
  ```

### Usage:

You can view your current `kubectl` configuration using the following command:

```
kubectl config view
```

It is possible to have several configuration files that you can add to the environment variable `KUBECONFIG`:

```
export  KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:config-demo:config-demo-2
```

You can also specify ‘kubectl’ config file in the command line:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig path/to/kubectl.conf get nodes
```

You can export your current `kubectl` config and use it on another workstation:

```
kubectl config view --flatten
```

### Articles:

Please find more information about `kubectl` configuration and usage in the following articles:

- [Configure Access to Multiple Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)
- [kubectl Cheat Sheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/)

### How to create:

You can create `kubectl` configuration manually or as a part of cluster creation process.

Here is how to create `kubectl` configuration for existing **kops** cluster( [link1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/kubectl.md), [link2](https://gist.github.com/jeffjohnson9046/295e7a032b9a910b0f9896e1c432e972) ):

```
# update cluster will do it automatically after cluster creation. 
# But we expect that if you're part of a team you might share the KOPS_STATE_STORE

# ASSUMPTION:  You have pointed kops to some location where the cluster configurations are stored 
# (I have this in my ~/.bash_profile):
export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://example-state-store

# Use kops to get the list of clusters
$ kops get clusters

# Export the configuration of the cluster you care about; this will update your ~/.kube/config file, so kubectl knows about it:
$ kops export kubecfg cluster-foo.example.com

# You can now use kubernetes using the kubectl tool:
$ kubectl get nodes
```

If you created your cluster using [**kubeadm**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/), `kubectl` config is located in `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` on the master node and you can just copy it to your home directory:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```